# Conda ResolvePackageNotFound Error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to run `conda env create` command in terminal, but I'm getting the following error:

```
`(base) *******-MBP:Tensorflow-Bootcamp-master ******$ conda env create -f tfdl_env.yml
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - libpng==1.6.30=vc14_1
  - six==1.10.0=py35_1
  - tk==8.5.18=vc14_0
  - openssl==1.0.2l=vc14_0
  - icu==57.1=vc14_0
  - wincertstore==0.2=py35_0
  - zlib==1.2.11=vc14_0
  - vs2015_runtime==14.0.25420=0
  - jpeg==9b=vc14_0
  - win_unicode_console==0.5=py35_0
  - qt==5.6.2=vc14_6`
```

I've tried updating Conda, but that's not working. Do I need to manually install each of these packages? I tried manually installing zlib, but it didn't remove it from the list of packages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. In my case, I deleted the packages mentioned in the error from the .yml file and I ran the command to create the environment. It worked fine. Those packages will be automatically downloaded while creating the environment. So, you don't have to manually install all those packages. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old one and create a new tfdl_env.yml and put that content

`name: tfdeeplearning
 channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- bleach=1.5.0=py35_0
- certifi=2016.2.28=py35_0
- colorama=0.3.9=py35_0
- cycler=0.10.0=py35_0
- decorator=4.1.2=py35_0
- entrypoints=0.2.3=py35_0
- html5lib=0.9999999=py35_0
- ipykernel=4.6.1=py35_0
- ipython=6.1.0=py35_0
- ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py35_0
- ipywidgets=6.0.0=py35_0
- jedi=0.10.2=py35_2
- jinja2=2.9.6=py35_0
- jsonschema=2.6.0=py35_0
- jupyter=1.0.0=py35_3
- jupyter_client=5.1.0=py35_0
- jupyter_console=5.2.0=py35_0
- jupyter_core=4.3.0=py35_0
- markupsafe=1.0=py35_0
- matplotlib=2.0.2=np113py35_0
- mistune=0.7.4=py35_0
- mkl=2017.0.3=0
- nbconvert=5.2.1=py35_0
- nbformat=4.4.0=py35_0
- notebook=5.0.0=py35_0
- numpy=1.13.1=py35_0
- pandas=0.20.3=py35_0
- pandocfilters=1.4.2=py35_0
- path.py=10.3.1=py35_0
- pickleshare=0.7.4=py35_0
- pip=9.0.1=py35_1
- prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py35_0
- pygments=2.2.0=py35_0
- pyparsing=2.2.0=py35_0
- pyqt=5.6.0=py35_2
- python=3.5.4=0
- python-dateutil=2.6.1=py35_0
- pytz=2017.2=py35_0
- pyzmq=16.0.2=py35_0
- qtconsole=4.3.1=py35_0
- requests=2.14.2=py35_0
- scikit-learn=0.19.0=np113py35_0
- scipy=0.19.1=np113py35_0
- setuptools=36.4.0=py35_1
- simplegeneric=0.8.1=py35_1
- sip=4.18=py35_0
- testpath=0.3.1=py35_0
- tornado=4.5.2=py35_0
- traitlets=4.3.2=py35_0
- wcwidth=0.1.7=py35_0
- wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
- widgetsnbextension=3.0.2=py35_0
- pip:
  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - jupyter-client==5.1.0
  - jupyter-console==5.2.0
  - jupyter-core==4.3.0
  - markdown==2.6.9
  - prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
  - protobuf==3.4.0
  - tensorflow==1.3.0
  - tensorflow-tensorboard==0.1.6
  - werkzeug==0.12.2
  - win-unicode-console==0.5
prefix: C:\Users\Marcial\Anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning`

Comment: Please leave more information if you want get some help